# Unable to get user's email ID in user_friends API of Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm fetching the list of user's friends who all are using the application with Login with Facebook feature. In GraphAPI for **"user_freinds"** request, I'm requesting for id, email & name of the users. However the API is not returning the email of users. Only name and ID of users are being returned. Please check the code below.

```
func getFacebookFriends() {
    if AccessToken.current != nil {
        let fbUserID = AccessToken.current?.userId ?? ""
        let friendsPath = "/\(fbUserID)/friends"
        let params = ["fields": "id, name, email"]
        let fbFriendsRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: friendsPath, parameters: params, httpMethod: .GET)
        fbFriendsRequest.start { (_, result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                print(response.dictionaryValue as Any)
                let responseDict = response.dictionaryValue!
                let data = responseDict["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
                if data.count != 0 {
                    // Sync the list with API
                } else {
                    // Show error 
                }
            case .failed(let error):
                // Show error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

> Also note that I'm using test users of Facebook, created by Developer portal of Facebook. Friends are added and authorised via Developer portal only.

Comment: Each of those friends would need to grant your app the `email` permission on their end, otherwise you don’t get access to it.

Comment: @CBroe Those permissions are granted for all test users via developer portal.

Comment: So you can get the email, if you just request the test user’s details using their own access token?

Comment: Yes. Using Login with Facebook functionality with the same test user, I received email of that one user. But didn't receive email in above case.

Comment: Might perhaps not be possible then, to request this field using a different user’s access token.

Comment: Looking on the docs you are missing user_friends permission. Maybe it could help?

Comment: if user_friends permission is not granted, he couldn't to get theirs list with id and name

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/) you are missing `user_friends` permission which needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Graph API Explorer to debug: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. Try to get permissions: 'GET/{user-id}/permissions'
3. Try to get friends list and separate user info in this tool
4. Email couldn't be visible if user hides it on privacy settings page